# ant does not recognize @ParametrizedTest and @CsvSource

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit5

Despite adding required dependencies, my ant (version 1.10.5) build fails to compile junit5 tests

I have pointed eclipse to the latest version of Ant separately installed in my system and also added all the jar files mentioned in the official Ant [page](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html) for junit-jupiter

The build script, taken from [ant-junit-samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-ant) page is as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project name="junit5-jupiter-starter-ant" default="build" basedir=".">

    <fail message="Ant 1.10.5 is required!">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <antversion atleast="1.10.5"/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>

    <path id="test.classpath">
        <pathelement path="build/test"/>
        <pathelement path="build/main"/>
        <fileset dir="${ant.home}/lib" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="build" description="clean build" depends="clean, test" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
        <echo message="${ant.home}" />    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/main"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/test"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/test-report"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac destdir="build/main" srcdir="src/main/java" includeantruntime="false"/>
        <javac destdir="build/test" classpathref="test.classpath" srcdir="src/test/java" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

    <!-- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-build-ant -->
    <target name="test.junit.launcher" depends="compile">
        <junitlauncher haltOnFailure="true" printSummary="true">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
            <testclasses outputdir="build/test-report">
                <fileset dir="build/test">
                    <include name="**/*Tests.class"/>
                </fileset>
                <listener type="legacy-xml" sendSysOut="true" sendSysErr="true"/>
                <listener type="legacy-plain" sendSysOut="true" />
            </testclasses>
        </junitlauncher>
    </target>

    <!-- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher -->
    <target name="test.console.launcher" depends="compile">
        <java classpathref="test.classpath" classname="org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher" fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="--scan-classpath"/>
            <arg line="--reports-dir build/test-report"/>
        </java>
        <junitreport todir="build/test-report">
            <fileset dir="build/test-report">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="build/test-report/html"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="test.junit.launcher, test.console.launcher" />

</project>
```

But I encounter the errors

```
[javac] import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
    [javac]                                ^
     org.junit.jupiter.params.provider does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] CalculatorTests.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} + {1} = {2}")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ParameterizedTest
    [javac]   location: class CalculatorTests
    [javac]  \CalculatorTests.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @CsvSource({
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CsvSource
    [javac]   location: class CalculatorTests
    [javac] 4 errors
```

Could you please guide on what i need to set right?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your classpath?

Comment: Sorry I haven't set my classpath explicitly. What would i need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **junit5-jupiter-starter-ant** sample copies the "standalone" JAR of JUnit 5 into the `$ANT_HOME/lib` folder. This primed Ant installation includes all packages JUnit 5 has to offer (Platform, Jupiter, Vintage) and passes them to the tasks that refer to the *ant runtime* via `class-path` or other means:

```sh
wget --directory-prefix "${ant_folder}/lib" "...junit-platform-console-standalone-1.3.2.jar"
```

See the `build.sh` for details: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-ant/build.sh

So, you may either:

- copy the `junit-platform-console-standalone-${version}.jar` to `ANT_HOME/lib`
- or add `junit-jupiter-params-${version}.jar` the same way as you did with `junit-jupiter-api-${version}.jar`